# Jcarousellite - highlight current item + captions

Tags: title, highlight, jcarousel, caption, jcarousellite

I'm using jcarousellite and jcarousel as well but I was wondering how to achieve to improvements:

1. Highlight current item - I show 5 thumbs, I want always to highlight the middle one (by a bit bigger size).
2. Captions - how to show title of only highlighted item (middle)?

I don't have a brightest idea how to start with that..

Answer (score 0):

do yo want to do something like this .. http://www.mako.co.il/

For this you can use two different carousels .

And bind the same next and previous buttons to both the carousels .

for the smaller carousel with 5 thumbs keep 'visible'= 5 and 'scroll' = 1
for the bigger image carousel  keep visible = 1 and scroll = 1.

position the bigger image carousel above the smaller image carousel by using absolute positioning .

I think this should help you achieve what you intend to do